# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context when using a view in a ForEach function SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I keep getting this error I can't seem to figure this out when I take out the return it still gives me a Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please file a bug report error

```
struct DailyLogView: View {
  
    
    @State var Meals : [meal]
    var columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 20), count: 2)
    
    var body: some  View {
      return ZStack{ //error here 
        
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 30){
          
                ForEach ( Meals ){ meal in
               
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15){
                    
                    
                        MealCardView( mealName: meal?.Name, totalCalories: meal?.totalCalories, mealTime: meal?.Time, mealImage: meal?.Image)
                    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made sure to make the Struct conform to Identifiable type

```
 struct meal : Identifiable {
    
    var id = UUID()
    var Name : String
    var Time : String
    var totalCalories : Int
    var Image : String

}
```

The error doesn't occur when I don't use the MealCardView so I think it might have to do with that.

```
struct MealCardView: View {
    
    
    @Binding var mealName:String
    @Binding var totalCalories:Int
    @Binding var mealTime:String
    @Binding var mealImage:String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            HStack{
                VStack{
                    Text(self.mealName)
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text("Calories:\(self.totalCalories)")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(10)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .cornerRadius(20)
    }
}
```

Comment: `MealCardView` expects a binding to a value, but you're passing it a value directly. Also, I strongly suggest you keep with the language convention and name types capitalized, e.g. `struct Meal {...}` and variables/properties camelCased: `var meals: [Meal]`

Comment: How would I pass MealCardView a Binding in this ForEach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MealCardView` expects a binding to a value, so you need to pass the binding to an array element.

You can do this by iterating over the indices of the array, and then use the projected value of the array subscript (which is a Binding) to the element.

First, I suggest you keep with the Swift naming convention and change your types to be Capitalized and properties/variables camelCased:

```
struct Meal: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String
    var time : String
    var totalCalories : Int
    var image : String
}
```

Also, instead of passing properties one-by-one, you can just pass the entire `Meal` variable

```
struct MealCardView: View {
   @Binding var meal: Meal
   // ...
}

struct DailyLogView: View {
   @State var meals: [Meal]

   var body: some View {
      
      ForEach(meals.indices, id: \.self) { index in
         MealCardView(meal: self.$meals[index])
      }

   }
}
```

Of course, if you insist on passing properties one-by-one, that's also possible, albeit unnecessarily verbose: `self.$meal[index].totalCalories`.